# How to validate Yup conditionally according to react state value?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a state called profession and I want to validate the form conditionally using Yup.
I'm aware that  we can validate according to another field. but in this case I'm checking the value of a react state. `profession` state will store the type of profession and in Yup schema I'll check the value of the profession and if it's `Student` I wanna have some validations.

```js
const [profession, setProfession] = useState(""); 

const SignupSchema2 = Yup.object().shape({
     universityname: Yup.string().when("profession", {
      is: "Student",
      then: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create an object that contain both the form state and your profession string and validate based on this object

```js
const [profession, setProfession] = useState("");
const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({});

const SignupSchema2 = Yup.object().shape({
   profession: Yup.string(),
   form: {
     universityname: Yup.string().when("profession", {
      is: "Student",
      then: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    })
   }
  });

// when you want to validate
SignupSchema2.validate({ profession, form: formValue });
```

Comment: I didn't understand what did you mean by "validate based on the object". can you make it clear?

Comment: Instead of simply validating the object that contain values of your form you can create an object that contain both the form values and the profession as you can see in the example

Comment: the problem is the profession field isn't part of formik. it's an external field and I'm setting data to it through useState in onClick. so can I validate the Yup using that state data?